# MoveWindow(), skip, dodge or bypass messaging?

Tags: c++, winapi, user32

I'm resizing a window with `MoveWindow()` but I don't own that window. I simply stole it from a different process and now I'm messing around with its hWindow.

However the process which I stole it from was running a message loop, handling some of those messages (`WM_MOVE`, `WM_SIZE`, `WM_GETMINMAXINFO`, etc.) which basically prevent me from doing whatever I want with it. Sometimes, it won't even let me size it past a given maximum which is key to making it run in fullscreen.

Except using asm, is there any way I can bypass messaging?

Comment: [SetWindowPos](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633545(v=vs.85).aspx) might work with `SWP_NOSENDCHANGING`. I've never tried it.

Comment: Why are you messing with another process's window?  It's not yours to play with.

Comment: @AdamRosenfield hold your horses man, I'm just fullscrewing* around with it. 

(* = making it fullscreen)

Comment: I see where you're coming from. Messing with other windows is pretty fun sometimes when you have some spare time and an idea. It involves restarting the computer a bit too often, though :p Of course in actual software, I would never suggest relying on other people's windows doing your bidding, though.

Comment: @chris =)) It's good. It's very good, it's funny. Anyways, SetWindowPos worked. If you want, you can wrap it up in an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`SetWindowPos`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633545%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) has a flag to not tell the window that you're doing something with it:

```
SetWindowPos (hwnd, 0, x, y, width, height, SWP_NOZORDER | SWP_NOSENDCHANGING);
```

As mentioned in the comments, relying on this behaviour in code you'll be using for more than having a bit of fun is not good, nor fair to the other windows, and you can very easily run into problems. [Raymond Chen](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/) has some particularly interesting blog posts on this, namely things like "What if two programs did this?"